# Unity arrays with string int and Sprites?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I made a Game and I want to store Data for each Item in a array.

How can I make this?

Want something like that:
array Itemname {id, name, cost, category, Image, ...}

Is it possible to make arrays with a mix of types (int, sprite, string,...)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a class that holds the related types.  For example:

```
public class Weapon {
    public string Name;
    public int Hitpoints;
}
```

Then declare a list of Weapons:

```
List<Weapon> Weapons = new List<Weapon>()
```

Then add weapons to your collection:

```
Weapons.Add(new Weapon{Name="Sword", Hitpoints=20})
Weapons.Add(new Weapon{Name="Gun", Hitpoints=60})
```

You can learn more about [Generic Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/when-to-use-generic-collections) on the MSDN Website.

Here is an introduction to [object oriented programming](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/object-oriented-programming-using-C-Sharp-net/).

Comment: Removed `{get; set;}` since that cannot be serialized for saving in Unity reducing the chances of OP asking that question next.